# Identifying the source of the memory leak in Googletest

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, googletest

I'm using GTest 1.7 to unit test C++ code in Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 7.

I've expanded GTest to try and do simple memory leak testing with `_CrtMem...` methods. (source: https://github.com/stbrenner/gtest_mem)

For the most part it all works great! However I currently have a case of a 44-byte memory leak being reported which I believe may be a false positive but I can't work out how to identify it to be sure.

The code I have to extend GTest is:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace testing
{
    class MemoryLeakDetector : public EmptyTestEventListener
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    public:
        virtual void OnTestStart(const TestInfo&)
        {
            _CrtMemCheckpoint(&memState_);
        }

        virtual void OnTestEnd(const TestInfo& test_info)
        {
            if(test_info.result()->Passed())
            {
                _CrtMemState stateNow, stateDiff;
                _CrtMemCheckpoint(&stateNow);
                int diffResult = _CrtMemDifference(&stateDiff, &memState_, &stateNow);
                if (diffResult)
                {
                    FAIL() << "Memory leak of " << stateDiff.lSizes[1] << " byte(s) detected.";
                }
            }
        }

    private:
        _CrtMemState memState_;
#endif // _DEBUG
    };
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners().Append(new testing::MemoryLeakDetector());

    RUN_ALL_TESTS();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm looking for, when it finds a leak, is a way to dump the area of memory that has apparently leaked so that I can try and identify where it's coming from.

I had hoped that adding `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` (before or after FAIL()) would have helped but that doesn't output anything extra.

Comment: If multiple threads are running or global variables are accessed (and heap allocated) between the checkpoints there can be false positives. Just be aware of that.

Comment: In the case in question, I'm actually starting a thread, then stopping it and deleting it. In theory this should have cleared everything. I've pretty much narrowed things down to a std::deque but am 99.9% sure that it should have all been handled correctly. If I could "see" the memory that has apparently leaked if would confirm/deny my assumption.

Comment: sizeof(testing::MemoryLeakDetector) = 56

Comment: And no global variables / statics.